# How to use JavaProgressBar with SwingWorker in a for loop?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I the following code:

```
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++) {
                    if(iteration==0){jProgressBar1.setValue(0);}
        jProgressBar1.setValue((int)(((iteration+1.)/iterations)*100));
                    jProgressBar1.setString(Integer.toString((int)(((iteration+1.)/iterations)*100))+"%");
```

and then come other steps and function calls. As it is now the `ProgressBar` has the value 0 at the start of the application and 100 when the for loop ends. I've looked over the tutorials and questions already asked but I don't know how to configure the SwingWorker functions to match my case. For example i don't know what `doInBackground()` should contain since the value of the bar depends only of the iterations and not on the results of the computations done in the loop.

I have tried using `publis` `process` but it does not show the update only a full bar at the end. This is the code now:

```
public class Algorithm extends SwingWorker<Void,Integer>{
    //variable declarations
    public void Run(MDVRPData data,String fileName, JTextArea jText, boolean method1,
            boolean method2, boolean method3, boolean twoOpt,
            boolean oneOneExc, boolean oneZeroExc, JSpinner iter, final JProgressBar jProgressBar1) {
        iterations=(Integer) iter.getValue();
        jText.setText("");
        jText.append("START ALGORITHM \n");
        jProgressBar1.setStringPainted(true);
        initDrawWindow(fileName);
        dr = new DecodeRoutes(twoOpt,oneOneExc,oneZeroExc);
        this.data=data;
        this.oneOneExc=oneZeroExc;
        this.twoOpt=twoOpt;
        this.oneZeroExc=oneZeroExc;
        this.bar=jProgressBar1;
        doInBackground();

}
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
        //initialization code
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++) {
            publish(iteration);
            //other computations and function calls
        }
        //function calls
        return null;
    } 
    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> iter) {
        int iteration=iter.get(iter.size()-1);
        bar.setValue((int)(((iteration+1.)/iterations)*100));
        bar.setString(Integer.toString((int)(((iteration+1.)/iterations)*100))+"%");            
    }
```

Comment: read oracle tutorial for working code example,

Comment: I red it but it shows an example where the progress bar depends on the things that happen in other functions and I didn't figure out how to adapt that to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my professors helped me solve the problem. Here is the code:

```
public class Algorithm extends SwingWorker<Void,Integer>{
    //variable declarations
    public Algorithm(MDVRPData data,String fileName, JTextArea jText, boolean method1,
        boolean method2, boolean method3, boolean twoOpt,
        boolean oneOneExc, boolean oneZeroExc, JSpinner iter, final JProgressBar jProgressBar1) {
        iterations=(Integer) iter.getValue();
        jText.setText("");
        jText.append("START ALGORITHM \n");
        jProgressBar1.setStringPainted(true);
        initDrawWindow(fileName);
        dr = new DecodeRoutes(twoOpt,oneOneExc,oneZeroExc);
        this.data=data;
        this.oneOneExc=oneZeroExc;
        this.twoOpt=twoOpt;
        this.oneZeroExc=oneZeroExc;
        this.bar=jProgressBar1;
        doInBackground();
    }  
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() {
         //initialization code
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++) {
            publish(iteration);
            //other computations and function calls
        }
        //function calls
        return null;
    }  
@Override
protected void process(List<Integer> iter) {
    int iteration = iter.get(iter.size() - 1);
    int procent = (int) (((iteration + 1.) / iterations) * 100);
    bar.setValue(procent);
    bar.setString(procent + "%");
}
```

And it is called like so:

```
    alg=new Algorithm(myData, fileName, jRadioButton1.isSelected(), jRadioButton2.isSelected(), jRadioButton3.isSelected(),
            jRadioButton4.isSelected(), jRadioButton5.isSelected(), jRadioButton6.isSelected(), (Integer)jSpinner1.getValue(), jProgressBar1);
    alg.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your progress bar from the doInBackground method you should enclose your update code in SwingUtilities.invokeLater or invokeAndWait method.

Something like this:

```
for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++) {
  final int itr = iteration;              
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         if(itr==0) {
           jProgressBar1.setValue(0);
         } else {
           jProgressBar1.setValue((int)(((itr+1.)/itr)*100));
           jProgressBar1.setString(Integer.toString((int)(((itr+1.)/itr)*100))+"%");
         }
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to override the swingWorker methods for my example.

Comment: And where is your example?

Comment: I've posted the `for loop` where I use `jProgressBar1`. The value of the bar does not depend only on the value of the `iteration`. The examples I've seen have in `doInBackground()` a return method that the bar uses to update. Do I need to have in `doInBackground()` the whole method containing the for loop that i use?

Comment: No. You can also use publish/process pair to update the progress bar. To do it you should call method publish in doInBackground and override the process to update your progress bar. But in this case you need to transfer in this method your current state.

Comment: I have added what I've tried but it still updates only at the end with 100.

Comment: You shouldn't do any long function calls after the loop because it will be displayed with 100% progress value.

Comment: I have long calls in loop and a graph plot after the loop.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how can I help you without to debug your code.